# How to hide rows in Sheet2 based on the criteria from Sheet1?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what I have so far....

```
Sub CopyItems()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1000", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Copies range and looks at the Column E in the target
        .AutoFilter 5, "Applicable", xlOr, "Not Applicable", 0 'two criteria in column 5
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).Resize(, 3).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Paste only 2 columns to target
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The current code copies rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on the criteria "Applicable" or "Not Applicable".

**Example Sheet1**

```
Row1  | UniqueID |  B    |    C   |    D    |       E        |
Row2  |     123  | testX |  XXXXX | YYYYYYY | Applicable     |
Row3  |     125  | testY |  XXXXX | YYYYYYY | Not Applicable |
Row4  |     125  | testZ |  XXXXX | YYYYYYY | Applicable     |
```

I would like the sheet2 to hide the rows that were copied based on the "Not Applicable" criterion.
This is what I am trying to accomplish after the code is executed on Sheet2

**Example what should be on Sheet2**

```
Row1  | UniqueID |  B    |    C   |
Row2  |     123  | testX |  XXXXX |
Row4  |     125  | testZ |  XXXXX |
```

Notice Row 3 was copied from Sheet1, but it is Hidden on Sheet2

Comment: Why do you want to copy the rows across and then hide them?

Comment: Why not apply a filter on sheet2 as you did on sheet1 ?

Comment: I agree.I would like to apply the filter on sheet2, but it seems that the code does not copy the column E (Applicable, Not Applicable) to sheet2 (which is what I want) so I do not have that column on sheet2. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this the easiest way will be to hide the rows separately after the first task has been completed.
You could use a reverse loop triggered from a button:

```
Dim r As Long, lastrow as Long
lastrow = range(A2).CurrentRegion.rows.count
For r = LastRow to A2 Step-1
  If Cell(r, 5).value = "not applicable" Then
    Rows(r).entirerow.hidden = True
  End If
 Next r
```

Comment: The column with value "Not Applicable" is not on the sheet2 it is only on sheet1. I would like the criteria from sheet1 to control what is filtered out on sheet2.